# How to use select filter with static values on async (server-side) ngTable

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I'm using ngTable 0.3.3 and am doing a async call to populate the table (pagination also done on server side). Here's my code:

```
var data = [];

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
  page: 1, 
  count: 10
}, {
  getData: function($defer, params) {
    // getData gets called when you click on a different page in the pagination links.
    // get the page number and size from params.$params
    var pageNumber = params.$params.page;
    var pageSize = params.$params.count;
    // set up the query parameters as expected by your server
    var mm = params.filter();
    var queryParams = {"page_size":pageSize, "page_number":pageNumber, "sorting": params.sorting(), role: mm.role, id: mm.id, email: mm.email};
    $log.log(mm.role);

    // $log.log(mm.role, mm.email);

    User.getCount().then(function (total) {
      User.query(queryParams).then(function (result) {
        params.total(total);
        $defer.resolve(result);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

with this html:

```
    <table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-custom">
      <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td data-title="'Name'">
          {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Role'" sortable="'role'" filter="{ 'role': 'text' }">
          {{user._role}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Email'" sortable="'email'" filter="{ 'email': 'text' }">
          {{user.email}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Created date'">
          {{user.created_at | date: 'dd MMM yyyy'}}
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Edit'">
          <a ui-sref="app.users.edit({userId: user.id})">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td data-title="'Edit'">
          <a ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

And both filtering and pagination works as expected. You can see I have a `$log` call which tells me when the filter is being triggered while I type in the text field. Now I'm trying to get the role as a select rather than a text field, so I changed my code like so:

```
$scope.roles = function (column) {
  var def = $q.defer();
  var docType = [{role: 'admin'}, {role: 'customer'}, {role: 'singer'}, {role: 'voiceArtist'}];

  def.resolve(docType);
  return def;
};

var data = [];

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
  page: 1, 
  count: 10
}, {
  getData: function($defer, params) {
    // getData gets called when you click on a different page in the pagination links.
    // get the page number and size from params.$params
    var pageNumber = params.$params.page;
    var pageSize = params.$params.count;
    // set up the query parameters as expected by your server
    var mm = params.filter();
    var queryParams = {"page_size":pageSize, "page_number":pageNumber, "sorting": params.sorting(), role: mm.role, id: mm.id, email: mm.email};
    $log.log(mm.role);

    // $log.log(mm.role, mm.email);

    User.getCount().then(function (total) {
      User.query(queryParams).then(function (result) {
        params.total(total);
        $defer.resolve(result);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

And this html:

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-custom">
          <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
            <td data-title="'Name'">
              {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Role'" sortable="'role'" filter="{ 'role': 'text' }">
              {{user._role}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Role1'" filter="{role: 'select'}" filter-data="roles($column)">{{user._role}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Email'" sortable="'email'" filter="{ 'email': 'text' }">
              {{user.email}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Created date'">
              {{user.created_at | date: 'dd MMM yyyy'}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Edit'">
              <a ui-sref="app.users.edit({userId: user.id})">Edit</a>
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Edit'">
              <a ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)">Delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

The roles (that I want to populate the select from) is a static array with five elements in it. I can see the select on the Role column, but is empty (doesn't show admin, customer, etc) and it doesn't trigger the filter. When I select an item, nothing happens anywhere. Wha am I missing here?

PS: I've seen similar questions and have even tried their plunker when was available, but the questions I've found they either use async values for the select (which I don't want to) or the whole data is static, which again, I don't want to. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

How I got it to work:

My js code:

```
$scope.roles = function (column) {
  var def = $q.defer();
  var docType = [{id: 'admin', title: 'Admin'}, {id: 'customer', title: 'Customer'}, {id: 'singer', title: 'Singer'}, {id: 'voiceArtist', title: 'Voice Artist'}];
  def.resolve(docType);
  return def;
};

var data = [];

$scope.deleteUser = function (id) {
  User.get(id).then(function (result) {
    $scope.tmpUser = result;
    $scope.tmpUser.remove().then(function (result) {
      if (result) {
        $scope.showAlert('User deleted successfully.', 'success');
        var n = true;
        angular.forEach(data, function (v, k) {
          if ($scope.tmpUser.id === v.id) {
            if (n) {
              data.splice(k, 1);
              $scope.tableParams.reload();
              n = false;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
};

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
  page: 1, 
  count: 10
}, {
  getData: function($defer, params) {
    // getData gets called when you click on a different page in the pagination links.
    // get the page number and size from params.$params
    var pageNumber = params.$params.page;
    var pageSize = params.$params.count;
    // set up the query parameters as expected by your server
    var mm = params.filter();
    var queryParams = {"page_size":pageSize, "page_number":pageNumber, "sorting": params.sorting(), role: mm.role, id: mm.id, email: mm.email};

    User.getCount().then(function (total) {
      User.query(queryParams).then(function (result) {
        params.total(total);
        $defer.resolve(result);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Its important to note that the array you pass must in the format of `[{id:'someId', title: 'SomeTitle'}, {...}]`

Comment: You don't want async or static data but you're using a static array and a promise. Are you looking for an alternative solution or a solution to the issue you have in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select is not populated because you're not waiting for the promise to resolve.

Here's a plunker that I stumbled upon when I faced this issue a few months ago:

[plnkr.co/edit/XJo9rp?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/XJo9rp?p=preview)

Try something like that:

```
function getData() {
    return $q.when([{role: 'admin'},...]);
}
var promise = getData();
```

Which is the short version for:

```
function getData() {
    var def = $q.defer();
    var docType = [{role: 'admin'},...];
    def.resolve(docType);
    return def;
}
var promise = getData();
```

and your scope function:

```
$scope.roles = function(column) {
    var select = promise.then(function(results) {
        return results;
    })
    return select;
};
```

Comment: When I tried your suggestion I got this error: Error: `Function roles($column) must be instance of $q.defer()` I literally copied and pated your code.... Should I have changed anything on the html side?

Comment: @WagnerMatosUK sorry I adapted an existing code using $http to your answer. Try the updated code instead

Comment: I found the plunker I stumbled upon when I faced that issue at work: http://plnkr.co/edit/XJo9rp?p=preview

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately that didn't work either. Go the same error: `Error: Function roles($column) must be instance of $q.defer()`

Comment: Thanks to the plunker you've sent earlier I got it to work. Would you like to amend your reply so I can mark as accepted? Thanks again for your help!